# Lock Service getScriptLock() does it work in libraries

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building a script library that will be used by multiple other scripts. These scripts will run simultaneously and I need to control the access to a single resource, a spreadsheet.

The documentation is not completely clear to me. The [Class Lock](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock) example refers to the `LockService.getPublicLock();` method. But that method does not seem to exist anymore.

To test the `LockService` I have created one library that has a method doTest that acquires a lock:

this.doTest = function (testClient) {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(),
        success;

```
try {
  lock.waitLock(1000);
  Logger.log(testClient + ' Obtained lock');
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  lock.releaseLock();
} catch (e) {
  Logger.log(testClient + ' Could not obtain lock after 2 seconds.');
}
```

}

The test library is used in two other test scripts. If I run the test scripts simultaneously both scripts sometimes fail to acquire the lock. This is exactly what I want to see.

But given the example in the documentation referring to another method and the usage of the library in different scripts, I would like to be sure this is how it is supposed to work.

So the question is: Does the script lock work across libraries and will it lock the section of code regardless if the library is used in different scripts. And are there any other issues I should worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are correct in your assumption: a Lock instance used in the library will be shared by all scripts  using the library. At least that is my assumption as well.

If you look at the [**Resource Scoping section of the Libraries page in Google Apps Script reference**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#scoping), and scroll down to the table of shared and non-shared resources, you will see that Lock is a *non-shared* resource, which is explained in the table footnote as

> *This means that library has its own instance of the resource/feature and that all
>   scripts that use the library share and have access to that same
>   instance*

The wording of that [Resource Scoping](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#scoping) section is rather confusing, I must say, with *'shared'* and *'non-shared'* concepts not explained very well. But the gist of it is: as long as your Lock is created in the library code, all scripts using that library will access the same instance of the lock.